# js get unique string identifier for class/method

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a unique string for a class that can be used to identify it and will always be the same for a class:

file 1:

```
class User {
    gender
    age
    firstname
    lastname

    get fullname() {
        return firstname + ' ' + lastname
    }
}
```

file 2:

```
class User {
    firstname
    lastname

    get fullname() {
        return firstname + ' ' + lastname
    }
}
```

I have a function that generates an identifier base on class / method names.
E.g. the identifier for the `fullname` method would be `User.fullname`.
Unfortunately this creates a conflict since both implementations of User (file 1 and 2) result in the same identifier.

Is there some way make them unique? I know that I could just add a random number or uuid, but it is important that the identifier is always the same and results purely from the structure of the object it describes.

Comment: Maybe you should add the filename to the identifier?

Comment: @JonasW. The code is being transpiled and bundled so I am not sure if the filename will work at runtime...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Answer (score 0):

You could name the classes differently like:

```
class User {
    constructor(gender, age, firstname, lastname) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    get fullname() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
    }
}
```

and then you have another class as:

```
class User2 {
    constructor(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    get fullname() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
    }
}
```

Then you can check the name of the newly created objects to determine if they are made using User1 or User2 as:

```
var user1 = new User('male', 21 'John', 'Smith');
var user2 = new User2('John', 'Smith');
console.log(user1.constructor.name);  // User
console.log(user2.constructor.name);  // User2
```

You could even use the `instanceof` to check to see if the object created is from the class that you are expecting:

```
console.log(user1 instanceof User)  // true
console.log(user2 instanceof User)  // false
```

This way you can do a check as described as above without needing to store some type of class identifier and you can keep the method names the same.

An important note with this though is that you will get a type error with `.constructor.name` if the object is undefined to begin with. So you'll need to do an undefined check beforehand.